# WSE 2.0 raises wse910 error

Tags: wse2.0

I had to use a [Microsoft Web Services Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977323.aspx) 2.0 service and it raised wse910 error when the time difference between the server and client was more than 5 minutes.

I read in many places that setting the `timeToleranceInSeconds`, `ttlInSeconds` and `defaultTtlInSeconds` values should help, but only setting the clock of the client machine solved the problem.

Any experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](http://geeknotes.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/more-wse-issues-timestamp-validation-and-clock-skew/) help? It also mentions setting timeToleranceInSeconds and defaultTtlInSeconds on the client as well as the server.